# Samba + Centos (Share not working)

Tags: network-shares, samba, centos, smb

I've done this a few times already, but for some reason this time it's not working.

I have a folder called *ruby* (*root:root - 0777*) on */home/placona*

I'm trying to see this folder from my WindowsXP box, but keep getting permission denied. I can see the global share though, but whenever I try clicking on the ruby share, it won't let me in.

Here's my *smb.conf* settings:

```
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/samba.%m
        guest account = nobody
        netbios name = DEVBOX
        server string = DEVBOX CENTOS
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        encrypt passwords = yes
        security = share
        max log size = 50

[ruby]
        path = /home/placona/ruby
```

I want to be able to open this folder without using password (hence the *guest account = nobody*).

I tried even with password, but never seems to work.

Can anyone spot anything wrong with my settings?

Answer (score 1):

Samba shares need both users and settings. I'm sure you already have CentOS users, but do you also have Samba users setup?

`smbpasswd -a joe`

you can also add the following line to your share definitions

```
[ruby]
valid users = joe randi insert-samba-user-here
```

Oh and make sure you reload samba via

`service smb restart`

(Note, most code taken from: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/adding-a-user-to-a-samba-smb-share/ )

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
read only = no
```

to your [ruby] section.

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your existing settings:

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User

[ruby]
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

You've already got the *guest account* setting to tell Samba which account to use as the guest user; *map to guest = Bad User* tells Samba to automatically convert an unrecognized username to the Guest user.

You may also want to put these in your *[ruby]* section (tweak the permissions as needed):

```
directory mask = 0777
create mask = 0666
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the file owner to nobody  then all groups can access the files.